# What is the highest possible score in 2048 hard?

Tags: puzzle, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

There is a [variant](https://sztupy.github.io/2048-Hard/) of the popular game 2048, called 2048 hard or 2048 impossible, which automatically places each new tile in the hardest possible location. Is this variation possible to solve, and if not, what is the highest possible score?

Edit: I guess I should have been a little more clear. First, I want to know if this variation is solvable. Then if the answer turns out to be no, I would like to know what the highest possible score is.

Edit 2: Perhaps I should clarify yet again. This variant contains no element of chance whatsoever, but it would be necessary to know the algorithm used to generate new tiles in order to create a solving algorithm. Then again, if someone has actually beaten the game, that would answer my question. Also, the scoring metric is the one posted in RandomUser's second comment.

Comment: I forget, what is the scoring metric for the game?  It seems to be unrelated to the current-largest value on the board...

Comment: The highest possible score is of course $2048$. I've finished the game recently. BTW, should I post the picture as the answer?

Comment: The program is thinking too much :). I don't like that :)

Comment: How does it determine "hardest possible location"?

Comment: @abiessu When you combine two tiles, you receive the value of the tile that is created.

Comment: @RandomUser: I guess the version I've played has a different metric then, because I've gotten scores as high as 12000 without getting the 2048 tile, or even having more than 2048 as the current sum of the board

Comment: @abiessu That actually sounds accurate. When you combine a pair of $2$s you get $4$ points. For making an $8$ you would get $8$ points, but inside that $8$ is the score for the pair of $4$s, making for $16$ total. So the score you have at the moment of making the $2048$ tile, if there was nothing else on the board when you did so, is between $18432$ (only $4$s were spawned) and $20480$ (only $2$s were spawned). In the standard game it averages to a little over $20000$. Of course you typically have a bit of a higher score, since there are usually a few combined tiles other than the $2048$ left.

Comment: I have once seen a list of highest score for the original $2048$ game. If I remember correctly, the highest score of that is something around 10 million. My average score for this hard version is about 5-10% of the original one. If we extrapolate, the highest score of this hard version is expected to be at least of the order of $10^5$.